# Open source editors using (Uni)SynEdit [except Dev-PHP/Dev-C++]

Tags: delphi, synedit, demos

does anyone know some good open source editors / IDES that are using SynEdit?
 this is very powerful control, but it definitely lacks some advanced demos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Syn text editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/syn/). Somewhat dated but should give you an idea.

Answer (score 3):

The Lazarus IDE is built around SynEdit.  That's about as advanced a "demo" as you can get.

Comment: Lazarus uses "own" version of synedit, fork of SynEdit 1.*something* version. It is quite different in fact. And, to be honest, I was looking for some less advanced demo ;) ;)

Comment: mwedit even. Though they synced later with some synedit version.

Answer (score 3):

Innosetup uses SynEdit and you can get the source to examine for free. I found the demos that come with Synedit quite acceptable though.
Bri

Answer (score 1):

My favorite programmer's editor, [**ConTEXT Editor**](http://www.contexteditor.org/) that recently has turned Open Source.

The project is hosted on Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

Tinn-R uses the latest version (UNICODE) of SynEdit:

- [Web page](https://nbcgib.uesc.br/tinnr/en/)
- [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinn-r/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/jcfaria/Tinn-R)